# UIAlertController addAction not working

Tags: ios, swift

So the UIAlertController is displaying the alert on the screen correctly, but in the xCode simulator pressing ok does nothing and it doesn't leave the alert. [alert view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0DL.png)

```
    func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String) {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that displayAlertMessage called from main thread?

Comment: Yes I am because, the correct string is being entered into user message.

Comment: Just a note; it's preferable to embed your image in the question (there's an image button when you're creating/editing a post), instead of linking to an external image.

Answer (score 1):

change UIAlertActionStyle.Default  to UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel

```
func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String) {

let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil);

myAlert.addAction(okAction);

self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);

}
```

and if you want to do something in ok

```
 let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
      //do whatever you want to do here
     // for e.g dismiss view controller or segue your view controller etc.
    }
```

Comment: Neither of those solutions worked. From documentation online it seems like  to dismiss the Alert Controller I would just need to leave the handler as nil, since I am returning to the same view.

Comment: it must be work . and r u using this on main thread? and what do you want exactly

Comment: Found the problem. I had slow motion enabled in the simulator.